# Instagram API, need input: snatch instagram images from specific hashtag over time and sync up to date like count for local sorting queries

Tags: php, mysql, api, instagram

Hello there and warning for wall of text :)

I am about to build a site that scrape and collects instagram photos belonging to five combos of two hashtags. The first hashtag will be the same and are the name of the site/campaign, the other hashtag till be one of five topics.

This also need to sort under the instagram username so that each user can "collect" images of all five topics.

This then needs to be presented as a "toplist" sorted by "number of images DESC, combined likes DESC". Where one image from each topic, in other words, five images are max for each user.

Kind of hard to explain, i'll try to illustrate it by this exampel of the toplist i need to build:

TOPLIST:

**Rank 1.**

```
USERNAME - score 27 (has collected all 5 topics and have most combined likes)

(img) #competition #topic-1 5 likes

(img) #competition #topic-2 3 likes

(img) #competition #topic-3 10 likes

(img) #competition #topic-4 5 likes

(img) #competition #topic-5 4 likes
```

**Rank 2.**

```
 USERNAME - score 25

(img) #competition #topic-1 5 likes 

(img) #competition #topic-2 3 likes

(img) #competition #topic-3 8 likes

(img) #competition #topic-4 5 likes

(img) #competition #topic-5 4 likes
```

**Rank 3.**

```
USERNAME - score 38 (has more likes than the leader but has only 4 topics covered..)

(img)#competition #topic-1 5 likes

(img) #competition #topic-2 3 likes

(img) #competition #topic-3 10 likes

(img) #competition #topic-4 20 likes
```

**Rank 4.**

```
USERNAME - score 17
(img) #competition #topic-1 1 likes

(img) #competition #topic-2 2 likes 

(img) #competition #topic-3 3 likes 

(img) #competition #topic-4 11 likes
```

And so on....

I have been poking around a little with the API and it seems like "/tags/tag-name/media/recent" would be my best, if not only "entry point" to this problem?

So what i'm thinking about doing is running a script each 5 minutes or something that till go trough the latest images tagged "#competition", then check if any of the 5 secondary tags are in there, and if so - save if not already in DB.

I guess i have to cache to fetch all images matching these tags over time? I have yet to reach Instagrams limit of objects per query... but if nothing else i will reach my own servers timeout if i try to load all each time.

The big pain in the ass from my point of view is the likes, since these need to be constantly updated from instagram to keep the scoreboard alive. Just looping trough all cached images with cron and then doing an api request to update each like count seems a bit heavy both for my server and instagrams api limit.

Maybe i can utilize logged in users sessions/tokens to do this in some smart way?

Or should i convince the rest of the team that this is a bad idea and we should build or own "voting" mechanism and keep the competition local, separated from instagrams like counters?

Please share your ideas of how you'd store and solve this :)

Comment: What did you end up doing with this? I have this almost exact situation andthe same problem with like counts. I plan to update the count value when users vote (piggy back on their authentication. I also plan on asyncly updating my DB at the speed of 4k request per hours, any photos that have not been updated in the past 6h.

Comment: This particular project never became reality.

However, what i have done on other projects where i cached instagram photos locally, i added a timestamp in the databased called "last_checked" or something.. then made a cron executed script that updates X posts per run, and with the posts with the lowest "last_checked" value ,to maintain a fresh database...

Comment: Right this sounds like that I thought, I guess it'll do :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the tags endpoint, like you suggested, is the way to go - this will return all the data you need - and store in a database. That way you can do all your calculations (aggregation of users, likes, etc.) and don't have to worry too much about rate limits, authentication etc.

Unfortunately, I don't think real-time update get's triggered on a like (which would be ideal for you) so your stuck with having to either go through all the images to get the like count or create you own like mechanism like you mentioned - not sure what your requirements are and how many users / pics you're expecting but if you spread it out over time (i.e. get x amount every x minutes) I don't see any problem server wise...

When you mention caching of images I'm assuming you mean storing the url and not the actual binary image data?